# Oracle: Need help matching multiple conditions but treated as one

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I start by looking at my records in a mysql database and generate an oracle query with an exclude list. I don't want to match a row in the oracle database if its value2, 3, and 4, combined equal one of the sets of () in the where clause. I cannot get this to work and I don't know why. Can anyone provide some insight?

Here is my current oracle query:

```
SELECT
    value1,
    value2,
    value3,
    value4
FROM
    table
WHERE
    AND value4 > 1
    AND (value2 != '102632151' AND value3 != '1111' AND value4 != '2')
    AND (value2 != '102632353' AND value3 != '1111' AND value4 != '3')
    AND (value2 != '102633090' AND value3 != '1111' AND value4 != '8')
ORDER BY
    value1 ASC
```

So lets say I have five rows in my database:

```
value1      value2          value3          value4
__________________________________________________
1           102632151       1111            2
2           102632200       1111            2
3           102632353       1111            3
4           102633000       1111            2
5           102633090       1111            8
```

My intent is to return the following rows:

```
value1      value2          value3          value4
-------------------------------------------------------
2           102632200       1111            2
4           102633000       1111            2
```

But, if the 5 rows in my database looked like this:

```
value1      value2          value3          value4
-------------------------------------------------------
1           102632151       2222 <-----     2
2           102632200       1111            2
3           102632353       1111            3
4           102633000       1111            2
5           102633090       1111            9 <-----
```

The query should return this:

```
value1      value2          value3          value4
-------------------------------------------------------
1           102632151       2222            2
2           102632200       1111            2
4           102633000       1111            2
5           102633090       1111            9
```

Comment: `AND` can't follow `WHERE` directly, seems a typo. But every AND says: "value3 not equal 1111`. Why do you expect rows with value3=1111?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the `where` clause to be:

```
WHERE value4 > 1 AND
      NOT (value2 = '102632151' AND value3 = '1111' AND value4 = '2') AND
      NOT (value2 = '102632353' AND value3 = '1111' AND value4 = '3') AND
      NOT (value2 = '102633090' AND value3 = '1111' AND value4 = '8')
```

I think `and not` most easily captures the logic you want.

EDIT:

You could also phrase this as:

```
WHERE value4 > 0 AND
      (value2 <> '102632151' OR value3 <> '1111' OR value4 <> '2') AND
      (value2 <> '102632353' OR value3 <> '1111' OR value4 <> '3') AND
      (value2 <> '102633090' OR value3 <> '1111' OR value4 <> '8')
```